# What is the correct way of sending credentials data using Angular Http Headers?

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I am struggling to find the best way of sending credentials because everything I find seems to me somehow insecure?
Is this the correct way of sending credentials? Shouldn't this be set in Authorization Headers with semicoln between username and password?(username:password) and then parsed to base64 string?
I am asking strictly about handling the submit on the login form not the later authorization using interceptors etc.

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(httpsUrl, { username, password })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            if (user && user.token) {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            }
            return user;
        }));
}
```

Comment: Why does this seem insecure? Your variable name suggests you're using HTTPS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have read somewhere that a good practice is to send credentials using authorization headers but I cant find any info on how to set those headers correctly

Comment: Read where? A good practice under what circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

It's more a question of following standards rather than strictly security. The authentication you are trying to do is commonly known as Basic Authentication.

There is a [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617) that outlines how to do Basic Authentication, and you are correct it does use request headers and base 64 encoded strings.

However, if your web server is already configured to allow you to send the credentials as part of the POST body, that is not any less secure.

It just doesn't follow the standard, which may or may not have any impact on your specific application.

Regarding the security aspect, as long as you are using SSL\HTTPS then the data will be encrypted over the wire regardless of which method you ultimately use.

An example of using this mechanism with Angular is as follows

```
// You need to import this class
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

login(username: string, password: string) {
    const encodedCredentials = btoa(`${username}:${password}`);
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedCredentials}`
        })
    };

    // This could now be get because we don't have a body
    return this.http.get<any>(httpsUrl, httpOptions)
        .pipe(map(user => {
            if (user && user.token) {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            }
            return user;
        }));
}
```

Comment: notice hes asking about the login part (posting user-pw, and receiving a session). its not the basic-auth-pass-me-user-pw-on-every-request-header

Comment: There is no backend I just took the most common schema for the login from internet tutorials and something there seems weird for me. If you have any guide for angular on how to set login credentials in authentication headers then I would really appreciate this.

Comment: @Stavm The login endpoint could use the Basic scheme for the initial request, give you a token, then all the other endpoints could use Bearer. Just because 1 endpoint could use Basic doesn't mean that they all need to.  It could also be using something like a session cookie. It's completely implementation specific.